# Cannot override properties in Hazelcast.yaml for Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, containers, hazelcast

I have Spring Boot application with Hazelcast (use 4.2 and also try to use 4.0.3 of hazelcast-all dependency). Hazelcast is configured for embedded topology. I use **TCP-IP** network join way. Properties for Hazelcast are set using file **Hazelcast.yaml** and Spring Boot property: `spring.hazelcast.config` (Spring by default use this name for Hazelcast config, it is redundant).

In property `member-list` I indicate IP addresses of two machines in one subnet (e.g. 192.0.0.1 and 192.0.0.2).

I build application in Docker using image based on Alpine on OpenJdk. Image includes start `java -jar` command as `ENTRYPOINT`.

**PROBLEM PREMISE:**

I run two docker containers on two machines described earlier. I forward only port 5701 (using `-p`) on both containers. And containers don't see each other. Spring Boot logs show that the container network is being used.

**PS:**

1. All work if run docker with `--net host`.
2. Also all work if I package Spring Boot application with property `public-address` in Hazelcast.yaml for two containers - once package with value 192.0.0.1, the other with value 192.0.0.2. Spring Boot Hazelcast instances see each other using network of machine (192.0.0.1 and 192.0.0.2).

**PROBLEM:**

I try to override property `public-address` in Hazelcast.yaml using:

- `docker run -e HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=192.0.0.1`
- `export HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=192.0.0.1 && docker run`
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Dhz.network.public-address=192.0.0.1"`
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=192.0.0.1"`
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/overrided_hazelcast.yaml"`
- `ENV HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=192.0.0.1` - in Dockerfile
- `ENTRYPOINT java -jar -Dhz.network.public-address=192.0.0.1 my-app.jar`

Nothing works. Does anyone know why it is not possible to override property `public-address` in the Hazelcast.yaml at startup?

Or maybe anyone knows how I can run two Spring Boot applications with embedded Hazelcast in separate Docker containers on separate machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set up Hazelcast public address is correct, at least starting from Hazelcast 4.1 where the [Config Override](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/configuration/overriding-configuration-settings.html) feature was added.

To check the working version, you can have a look at [Hazelcast Guide: Embedded Hazelcast on Kubernetes](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-embedded/). Instead of Hazelcast Kubernetes configuration, you can use TCP-IP. The following Hazelcast configuration worked for me (my host IP is `172.22.41.210`).

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: hazelcast-cluster
  network:
    join:
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 172.22.41.210:5701
          - 172.22.41.210:5702
```

Then, building and starting two applications should form a cluster.

```
$ mvn package && docker build -t hazelcast-embedded .
$ docker run --rm -e HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=172.22.41.210 -p 5701:5701 hazelcast-embedded
$ docker run --rm -e HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=172.22.41.210:5702 -p 5702:5701 hazelcast-embedded
```

You should see that the cluster was formed in the application logs.

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
        Member [172.22.41.210]:5701 - 21af9e1a-7e98-4305-905c-451ee23486c3 this        
        Member [172.22.41.210]:5702 - 0507d970-1f31-4df3-9ea5-8c3981eb7c98     
]
```

Comment: Thank you!
My mistake is I didn't try override properties with Hazelcast of version upper 4.1